# Android, Native error outputs in LogCat

Tags: android, native, logcat, android-logcat, alljoyn

I'm working with the alljoyn-sdk which uses native code. I get some strange error messages while running my application. I don't really know how to understand them. They look for example like this (in column 'text' in the LogCat-view):

```
1.017 ****** ERROR         DiscoveryManager  .../ice/HttpConnection.cc:157 |  0x1010
```

What do the particular terms mean?

thx & regards

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard AllJoyn status error which can be broken into parts

- `1.017`
- `****** ERROR`
- `DiscoveryManager`
- `.../ice/HttpConnection.cc:157`
- `0x1010`

the first `1.017` is a time-stamp from when the error was produced vs. how long the program was running in your case the program had only been running 1 second when the error occurred.

the second `****** ERROR` is the severity of the status.  If you are using the release version of Alljoyn only the highest status will be printed.  which is ERROR I think the '******' is there to make it simpler to find when debugging.

the 3rd `DiscoveryManager` is the AllJoyn module name.  AllJoyn is broken down into many modules in this case it is the DiscoveryManager associated with the ICE transport I only know its from the ICE transport because of the 4th option.

the 4th `.../ice/HttpConnection.cc:157` is the file name and line number that caused this output.

the 5th `0x1010` and most useful part is the status code for the error this error code can be looked up in the status.h file or Status.java file.  (depending on the language you are using)

`0x1010` is the `BAD_HOSTNAME` status.

This could mean that you don't have Internet connection or is could be a result some code that was in a version of AllJoyn before verson 3.4.

If you are not using the ICE transport you can ignore this error.